# Replacing script tag of maddhatter fullcalendar package in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I am using the maddhatter fullcalendar package in my Laravel application. In the script tag i have this line of code - `{!! $calendar->script() !!}`. is there any other way to replace this code where it's not written in a shortcut form because I want to add different functions inside the fullcalendar function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does that script render? I guess you could just write the Javascript by hand as per the fullCalendar documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to delete or replace the code - `{!! $calendar->script() !!}` in your blade.. 
 If you want to add more functions, you can add it to Javascript and some of function may need calendar ID. You can set the id - `setId('idname')` or get the id `getId()`. 
 *If you use setId, then your calendar id must be `#calendar-idname`

(^_^)